# How can I make a textBox print a variable in between a certain text?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

For example, I need richTextBox2 to print whatever is in between "AaBb" and "CcDd" at richTextBox1.

```
if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains ("AaBb x CcDd"))
    //print whatever is x in richTextBox2
```

Edit: I forgot to mention what i'm trying to do. I´m trying to scrape a website and print the value in the richTextBox (Euro to Dollar for example).
This is my code so far. Unfortunnaly, it doesn't work on both answers.

Version 1:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BitPrice
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient priceVariationDollar = new WebClient();
            string dollarPrice = priceVariationDollar.DownloadString("https://www.xe.com/pt/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=EUR&To=USD");
            euroTextBox.Text = dollarPrice;
            if (euroTextBox.Text.Contains("<span class=converterresult - toAmount></span>"));
            {
                int p1, p2;
                p1 = euroTextBox.Text.IndexOf("<Span class=converterresoult - toAmount>");
                p2 = euroTextBox.Text.IndexOf("</span>");
                if (p2 > p1 + 4)
                {
                    dollarTextBox.Text = euroTextBox.Text.Substring(p1 + 4, p2 - p1 - 4);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Version 2:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BitPrice
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient priceVariationDollar = new WebClient();
            string dollarPrice = priceVariationDollar.DownloadString("https://www.xe.com/pt/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=EUR&To=USD");
            euroTextBox.Text = dollarPrice;
            if (euroTextBox.Text.Contains("<span class=converterresult - toAmount></span>"));
            {
                var startIndex = euroTextBox.Text.IndexOf("<span class=converterresult - toAmount>") + "<span class=converterresult - toAmount>".Length;
                var endIndex = euroTextBox.Text.IndexOf("</span>");
            if (startIndex >= 0 && endIndex > startIndex)
                dollarTextBox.Text = euroTextBox.Text.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if it´s too long

Comment: You are basically asking a question about `string` manipulation. `Textbox` keyword in the question is unneccessary

Comment: You should not use the number 4, but the length of the first searched string, I used 4 as you said "AaBb".

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first check whether these two text are in `richTextBox1`, then if they both exit, you see if the first one comes before the second, then you take what is between.

```
int p1, p2;
string t1, t2;
t1 = "....."; //Your first searched text
t2 = "..."; //Your second searched text
p1 = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(t1);
p2 = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(t2);
if (p2 > p1 + t1.Length)
    richTextBox2.Text1 = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(p1 + t1.Length, p2 - p1 - t1.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var startIndex = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("AaBb") + "AaBb".Length;
var endIndex = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("CcDd");

if (startIndex >= 0 && endIndex > startIndex)                             
    richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```